# Will Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade gnome-shell version 3.28 to newer version since GNOME no longer supports it?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, upgrade, gnome-shell

```
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.28.4

$ ubuntu-software --version
gnome-software 3.28.1

$ uname -srvpo
Linux 5.3.0-28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 06:14:09 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I understand from GNOME that Gnome-shell 3.28 is no longer supported upstream. Will Ubuntu 18.04 be upgrading it's "gnome-shell" to a newer version than 3.28 to provide a better user experience on Ubuntu 18.04 given it is an LTS version?

If it is not upgraded, is Canonical providing gnome-shell support?

Comment: Canonical/Ubuntu support the software during the lifetime of the release.  That means the security fixes made to later releases will be back-ported to the supported version (fixes, not new features).  The only time this won't occur, is if that involves more work than providing the newer release & testing that (which is very unlikely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canonical/Ubuntu support the software during the lifetime of the release.

That means the security fixes made to later releases will be back-ported to the supported version (fixes, not new features).

The only time this won't occur, is if that involves more work than providing the newer release & testing that (which is very unlikely). There are cases where this has happened, but usually it's minor packages, and not major software suites such as GNOME.

> Maintenance updates will be provided for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop,
>   Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, and Ubuntu Base. All the remaining
>   flavours will be supported for 3 years.

https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/08/08/ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-released/

Also useful is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#Components

> When you install software from the main component, you are assured
>   that the software will come with security updates and that commercial
>   technical support is available from Canonical.

Comment: Am I correct to understand that gnome-shell ver 3.28 will be used through the lifetime of Ubuntu 18.04 and will not be upgraded until the next LTS is released?

Comment: Yes I believe that would be 99.999% correct. Canonical still have the right to upgrade 3.28 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes) to a later release should that involve less work than just back-porting security fixes to the current 3.28, as it's supported for 5 year sfrom release - but that is unlikely.